# Confusion on how to use strchr in C

Tags: c, strchr

```
char *strchr( const char *s, int c );
```

I understand that strchr locates the first occurrence of character `c` in string `s`. If `c` is found, a pointer to `c` in `s` is returned. Otherwise, a `NULL` pointer is returned.

So why does below code outputs num to strlen(string) rather than what its designed to do?

```
num=0;
   while((strchr(string,letter))!=NULL)
   {
      num++;
      string++;
   }
```

But this code gives correct output

```
num=0;
   while((string=strchr(string,letter))!=NULL)
   {
      num++;
      string++;
   }
```

I fail to see why assigning the pointer that's returned to another qualified pointer even makes a difference. I'm only just testing if return value is a NULL pointer or not.

Comment: Other notes about `strchr( const char *s, int c )`: The searched _string_ includes the _null character_ so `strchr(some_strings, 0)` never returns `NULL`.  The search is done as if `*s` and `ch` were converted to `unsigned char`.

Comment: This is how I see it: pointer to first `\0` is returned,ie at end of string. Since `(string=strchr(string, letter))!=NULL` will be true at this point, `string++` will occur and string will point beyond its allocated memory. Does this cause some sort of wierd behaviour to never return `NULL`? OR am I winding down the wrong track here?

Comment: Leon, `letter` with the value of the _null character_ is an unlikely case. But if code does need to handle this, could use `while((string=strchr(string,letter))!=NULL && *string)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `string` is a pointer.
2. In the first example, you just move it right one position, regardless of where (or if!) "letter" was found.
3. In the second example, every time you find a "letter", you:

   a) update "string" to point to the letter, then

   b) update "string" again to point just past the letter.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to put it in different way,

[`strchr`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.2p1)

> returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the character does not occur in the string.

In first part of your snippet return value is not being captured, immediate next position of `string` from where earlier it was pointing is passed as a argument. 
In short the snippet is counting total number of character till last appearance of `letter`

```
const char* string = "hello"
char letter = 'l'
num=0;
while((strchr(string,letter))!=NULL)
{
    num++;
    string++;
}
```

Like this,

```
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
              ^
              |
+-------+     |
+string +-----+
+-------+
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
                  ^
                  |
+-------+         |
+string +---------+
+-------+

            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
                      ^
                      |
+-------+             |
+string +-------------+
+-------+



            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
                              ^
                              |
+-------+                     |
+string +---------------------+
+-------+
```

In second snippet, return value of `strchr` is captured back into `string` and immediate next address is passed as argument in next iteration,

```
const char* string = "hello"
char letter = 'l'
num=0;
while((string = strchr(string,letter))!=NULL)
{
    num++;
    string++;
}
```

Something like this,

```
+-------+     
+string +-----+
+-------+     |
              |
/*input pointer to strchr*/
              |
              v
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
                      |
                      |
               /*return pointer from strchr*/
                      |
+-------+             |
+string +<------------+
+-------+     


+-------+                 
+string +-----------------+
+-------+                 |
                          |
            /*input pointer to strchr*/
                          |
                          v
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
                          |
                          |
              /*return pointer from strchr*/
+-------+                 |
+string +<----------------+
+-------+     

+-------+                     
+string +---------------------+
+-------+                     |
                              |
                /*input pointer to strchr*/
                              |
                              v
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+
            |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'/0,|
            +---+---+---+---+---+----+

                   /*NULL return from strchr*/
+-------+                     |
+string +<--------------------+
+-------+
```

Comment: for the visuals, helped me understand it instantly +1 .

Answer (score 0):

**First code snippet:**

> So why does below code outputs num to strlen(string) rather than what its designed to do?

The output may not be `strlen(string)` always and will be depend on the input string `string` and the character `letter` passed to `strchr()`. For e.g. if the input is

```
string = "hello"
letter = 'l'
```

then the output you will get is `4` which is not equal to the length of string `"hello"`. If the input is

```
string = "hello"
letter = 'o'
```

then the output you will get is `5` which is equal to the length of string `"hello"`. If the input is

```
string = "hello"
letter = 'x'
```

then the output you will get is `0`.
The output is actually depends on the position of last occurrence of the character `letter` in the input string.

Reason is that there is only one statement which is modifying the position of `string` pointer and that statement is

```
      string++;
```

It is working in this way -
If the character present in the `string`, the `strchr()` will return a not null value till the time the input `string` pointer point to a character on or before the last occurrence of character `letter` in the string. Once `string` pointer point to one character after the last occurrence of `letter` character in the string, the `strchr()` will return `NULL` and loop exits and `num` will be equal to position of the last occurrence of `letter` character in the string. So, you will get the output within the range from `0` to `strlen(string)` and not `strlen(string)` always.

```
string = "hello", letter = 'e', num = 0
strchr(string, letter) will return not null as 'e' present in input string
num++; string++;

string = "ello", letter = 'e', num = 1
strchr(string, letter) will return not null as 'e' present in input string
num++; string++;

string = "llo", letter = 'e', num = 2
strchr(string, letter) will return null as it does not find 'e' in input string and loop exits

Output will be 2
```

**Second code snippet:**

> But this code gives correct output

Yes, the reason is the `strchr()` returned pointer is assigned to `string` pointer. Take the same example as above, assume the input is

```
string = "hello"
letter = 'l'
```

`strchr(string, letter)` will return the pointer to first occurrence of character `l` and it is assigned to pointer `string`. So, now the string pointer pointing first occurrence of `l`. Which means, now the `string` is

```
string = "llo"
```

and in loop body you are doing

```
string++;
```

which will make the string pointer point to next character to the character returned by `strchr()`. Now the `string` is

```
string = "lo"
letter = `l`
```

and `strchr(string, letter)` will return the pointer to character which the `string` is pointing to currently as it is matching to character `letter`. Due to `string++` in the loop body, now the string will point to next character

```
string = "o"
letter = `l`
```

and `strchr(string, letter)` will return `NULL` and loop will exit. `num` is incremented as many times as the character `letter` found in `string`. Hence the second snippet is giving correct output.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the part about it not always outputting strlen of string